# How can I remove blank line breaks from an excel cell with VB or a formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I have many cells where data is broken up into many lines; some of those lines are blank. Is there a VB function or formula to remove blank line breaks in Excel cells, or all line breaks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: how do I remove all carriage returns from a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860184/excel-how-do-i-remove-all-carriage-returns-from-a-cell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substitute in a cell for linefeed seems to work - `=Substitute(A1, CHAR(10), "")`

Comment: It is possible that Char(13) (ie return) is included as well as line feed. The usual order is Char(13)+Char(10) but vice versa is possible.

Comment: @Remou is right. Use `=Substitute(Substitute(A1, CHAR(10), ""), CHAR(13), "")` to guard against this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is very old but I could not find anything that would do this. So I finally put this together from all the forums.

Select CELL or Range and this will remove All line breaks from the left and right, and removes any blank lines. Then Trim it all to look good. Alter as you see fit. I also made one that removes All Line Breaks, if interested. TY

```
    Sub RemoveBlankLines()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim strOldVal As String
    Dim strNewVal As String

    For Each rngCel In Selection
        If rngCel.HasFormula = False Then
            strOldVal = rngCel.Value
            strNewVal = strOldVal
            Debug.Print rngCel.Address

            Do
            If Left(strNewVal, 1) = vbLf Then strNewVal = Right(strNewVal, Len(strNewVal) - 1)
            If strNewVal = strOldVal Then Exit Do
                strOldVal = strNewVal
            Loop

            Do
            If Right(strNewVal, 1) = vbLf Then strNewVal = Left(strNewVal, Len(strNewVal) - 1)
            If strNewVal = strOldVal Then Exit Do
                strOldVal = strNewVal
            Loop

            Do
            strNewVal = Replace(strNewVal, vbLf & vbLf, "^")
            strNewVal = Replace(strNewVal, Replace(String(Len(strNewVal) - _
                        Len(Replace(strNewVal, "^", "")), "^"), "^", "^"), "^")
            strNewVal = Replace(strNewVal, "^", vbLf)

            If strNewVal = strOldVal Then Exit Do
                strOldVal = strNewVal
            Loop

            If rngCel.Value <> strNewVal Then
                rngCel = strNewVal
            End If

        rngCel.Value = Application.Trim(rngCel.Value)
        End If
    Next rngCel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you Just want ALL line Breaks gone use this.

```
    Sub RemoveLineBreaks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim strOldVal As String
    Dim strNewVal As String

    For Each rngCel In Selection
        If rngCel.HasFormula = False Then
            strOldVal = rngCel.Value
            strNewVal = strOldVal
            Debug.Print rngCel.Address

            Do

            strNewVal = Replace(strNewVal, vbLf, " ")

            If strNewVal = strOldVal Then Exit Do
                strOldVal = strNewVal
            Loop

            If rngCel.Value <> strNewVal Then
                rngCel = strNewVal
            End If
        End If
        rngCel.Value = Application.Trim(rngCel.Value)
    Next rngCel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula clean e.g =clean(A1). This removes all non-printing characters, and works in Mac versions of excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TrimEmptyLines()
Dim cel As Range, s As String, len1 As Long, len2 As Long
For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If Not IsError(cel.Value2) Then
        If InStr(1, cel.Text, vbLf) > 0 Then
            s = Trim(cel.Value2)
            Do ' remove duplicate vbLf
                len1 = Len(s)
                s = Replace$(s, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)
                len2 = Len(s)
            Loop Until len2 = len1

            ' remove vblf at beginning or at end
            If Left$(s, 1) = vbLf Then s = Right$(s, Len(s) - 1)
            If Right$(s, 1) = vbLf Then s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 1)

            cel.Value = Trim$(s)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

If this does not need formulas -

Add a new column immediately to the right of your data (touching the last column).
Insert into this column the numbers 1, 2, 3, etc, to the last row of your data, indicating the original order of the data.

Sort the data on any field except this new column.
All the blank rows will be sorted to the top or bottom of the data.
Delete all the contiguous blank rows.
Sort on the column you added to retain the original data row order.
Delete the column you added.