# Excel: how do I remove all carriage returns from a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get rid of all the carriage returns in my cell. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove blank line breaks from an excel cell with VB or a formula?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321078/how-can-i-remove-blank-line-breaks-from-an-excel-cell-with-vb-or-a-formula)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`=CLEAN(A1)`

Clean removes all nonprintable characters from text. -- Excel Help Documentation

Comment: Such a simple Clean solution

Comment: This also removes line feeds (`\n`), not only carriage returns...

Answer (score 19):

Assuming your cell is in A1, you can use the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")
```

Depending on the carriage return, you may have to use `char(13)` instead of `char(10)`.

Comment: Changing `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")` to `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")` will replace all carriage returns with a space. This will prevent two words combining in to one when you remove the carriage returns.

Answer (score 4):

Select the cell or cells, click Data/Text To Columns form Excel's menu bar,
choose the Delimited option on the first dialog page, click the Next button,
uncheck everything except Other and type Ctrl+J into the field next to it
(you won't see anything in that box, but the column layout chart will show
that it is being split at the line feeds (they are not carriage returns)...
then just click the Finish button.

Answer (score 4):

=Clean(A1)

This command can be found in Excel under the formulas tab > text.

Comment: this is exactly the same as the accepted answer. Please delete it

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RemoveLineBreaks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim strOldVal As String
    Dim strNewVal As String

    For Each rngCel In Selection
        If rngCel.HasFormula = False Then
            strOldVal = rngCel.Value
            strNewVal = strOldVal
            Debug.Print rngCel.Address

            Do

            strNewVal = Replace(strNewVal, vbLf, " ")

            If strNewVal = strOldVal Then Exit Do
                strOldVal = strNewVal
            Loop

            If rngCel.Value <> strNewVal Then
                rngCel = strNewVal
            End If
        End If
        rngCel.Value = Application.Trim(rngCel.Value)
    Next rngCel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```