# how to remove carriage return end of a Word table cell?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Pasting html data into a Word table cell.it creates **carriage return** end of table cell.How to remove carriage return only the end of table cell.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860184/5962841 - How can I remove blank line breaks from an excel cell with VB or a formula?

Comment: word table cell

Comment: Next time set the tags yourself, it helps you get better answers!

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want/expect - You use the VBA tag, but there's no background. Do you already have code - please show it so that we know where to start. Any answer we give you will be out of context...

Comment: Please see the image

Comment: Dim rngcell As Range
Set rngcell = Selection.Cells(1).Range
rngcell.Start = rngcell.End - 2
rngcell.Text = Replace(rngcell.Text, vbCr, "")

Comment: above code works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will remove a ¶ before the end of cell marker

```
Dim rngcell As Range
Set rngcell = Selection.Cells(1).Range
rngcell.Start = rngcell.End - 2
rngcell.Text = Replace(rngcell.Text, vbCr, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the Carriage returns and resize the rows

```vb
Public Sub removeCR(ByRef rng As Word.Table)
    For Row = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        For col = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
            Call tbl.Cell(Row, col).Select
            With Selection
                If Len(.Text) > 2 Then
                    If Mid(.Text, Len(.Text) - 2, 1) = vbCr Then
                        Let .Text = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 3) & chr$(7)
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next col
        Let tbl.Rows(Row).HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
    Next Row
End Sub
```

if you have to remove multiple of the carriage returns, or have to deal with linefeeds then you may consider a modification to the innermost `If` statement such as

```vb
While Mid(.Text, Len(.Text) - 2, 1) = vbCr Or _
        Mid(.Text, Len(.Text) - 2, 1) = vbLf
    Let .Text = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 3) & Chr$(7)
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

As will the following - for all terminating paragraph marks in all cells in all tables in the document:

```
Dim Tbl As Table, TblCell As Cell, Rng As Range
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  For Each TblCell In Tbl.Range.Cells
    Set Rng = TblCell.Range
    With Rng
      .End = .End - 1
      Do While .Characters.Last = vbCr
        .Characters.Last = vbNullString
      Loop
    End With
  Next
Next
```

It's better, though, not to insert them in the first place and, until we see the OP's code, we can't advise on how best to achieve that.